# Ecommerce database duplicated fileds

Tags: database, e-commerce

I'm making an ecommerce database and I want to know how to represente cart items and order items without duplicating fields ( productId, quantity ):

cart( id, userId)

cart_items ( id, cartId, **productId, quantity**)

order(id, userId)

order_items ( id, orderId, **productId, quantity**)

So after the order is done, all cart items are removed, I do not feel comfortable with this solution and I'm looking for the one that doesn't duplicate fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**If I understood correctly, might do something like this:**

product(id)

cart(id, userId)

order(id, userId)

items(id, productId_fk, orderId_fk, cartId_fk, quantity)

**Cart items with their cart:**
SELECT * FROM cart LEFT JOIN items ON cart.id = items.cartId_fk

**or cart_items of cart with id = 2:**
SELECT * FROM items WHERE cartId_fk = 2

Similarly for order_items.

Comment: As Virtual Anomaly showed, only cartId_fk is filled at first and orderId_fk is null, and then when orderId_fk is added, cartId_fk is nulled.You newer have both filled at the same time and when selecting cart items they will never also be order items. So to get current cart items you can use   WHERE cartId_fk = <currentCartId>    as shown below.

Comment: Thank you I understand now. So every time orderId_fk is added, should I create a new cart for the user ? or forcing one cart for one user, then ' Select * from items where cartId_fk =<user_cart_Id> and orderId_fk=null ' to return cart items ?

Comment: Or just removing the cart table and adding status field to order so it will be like this :
order( id, userId, status )
items ( id, orderId_fk, productId_fk, quantity)

Comment: A user has a cart of items. He goes to checkout. 
'Select * from items where cartId_fk =<user_cart_id>' are the cart items. 
You don't need orderId_fk = null because there are no items that have 'cartId_fk =<user_cart_Id>' and also orderId_fk not being null.

So after checkout is confirmed you create new order. You null the cartId_fk of user cart items and fill orderId_fk.
UPDATE items SET orderId_fk = <new_order_id>, cartId_fk = null WHERE cartId_fk = <user_cart_id>.

Comment: I would not remove cart table, and add the status field to order, as order is order only when it's checked out, not while items are still just in cart. So would not make sense conceptually for me but would work.

Comment: So user and cart will have one to one association ? 
cart (id , userId (unique) )

Comment: Inside cart and order, field userId is foreign key and doesn't have to be unique, so better name it userId_fk. Depending on your concept it might be more logical for user to have one shopping cart, or maybe many if you have e-commerce site with several different sections or you want to support different people shopping through the same account (different family members for instance). Anyways its your choice, would work both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an intermediate mapping table:

```
| id | cartId_fk | orderId_fk | productId_fk | quantity |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 24        | null       | 54           | 3        |
| 2  | 24        | null       | 45           | 7        |
| 3  | 24        | null       | 32           | 1        |
| 4  | null      | 98         | 89           | 5        |
| 5  | null      | 98         | 72           | 2        |
```

Either the CartID field or the OrderID field would be populated.

The CardID would be removed and the OrderID added, at the point of successful checkout.

Comment: Thank you. so how to select the current cart with its items ?

Comment: I'll add a couple more rows into the table so it's a bit clearer, but you would `SELECT * FROM <tablename> where cartId_fk = <currentCartId>`

Comment: yes but this will return order items also. I want just cart items that are not ordred yet